# Show json error tag in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json in an Api with an error tag. Now I want to show the error content in c# when an error occurs. Does anyone have a code or an example for this?

--Edited--

```
string html = string.Empty;
string url = @"http://henn.worteus.eu/?tag=getdatas&token=21123&id=" + sessions;

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.ContentType = "application/json";
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader re = new StreamReader(stream);
string json = re.ReadToEnd();

// Wrapper w = (Wrapper)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json, typeof(Wrapper));
Wrapper w = (Wrapper)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Wrapper));

dataGrid.ItemsSource = w.data;
```

Here are the data models

```
public class Data
{
    public string Skala { get; set; }
    public string Wert { get; set; }
    public string Bereich { get; set; }
    public string Interpretationen { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Might want to include some example JSON as well.

Comment: An example of what, exactly?  What does the code in the question have to do with your question?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to show error content in c#`?

Comment: This code get a json data from an Api. And I have als an error tag in the json. Now I want to show the content of the error tag when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an `error` property on the returned model

```
{
    "error":"...",
    "data":[...]
}
```

then desrialize the json to a strong type and then access the property

```
Wrapper w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json);
var data = w.data; 
var error = w.error;
if(error != null) {
    //...perform some action
}
```

Comment: Show an example of the json and also the `Wrapper` class

Comment: @dfsad based on you latest update the `Wrapper` class already has an `error` property. You can access it the same way you access the `data` property

Comment: but how can i do this with my posted code. With try and catch?

Comment: No. you check to see if `error` property is not `null` then do something if it is not.

Comment: When i have such code for example 

JObject RohwertObject = JObject.Parse(Rohwert);

JToken luegenskalaNorm = RohwertObject["data"].First["Rohwert"];
int LuegenskalaNorm = luegenskalaNorm.ToObject<int>();

Comment: @dfsad why do u want to do it without wrapper class?